# How to write a form editor?

Tags: vb.net, forms, layout, vb6, editor

I'm trying to write a print layout editor in VB6 or VB.Net, and am looking for some reference articles to help get me started.

The idea is that the editor will be used to define print "areas" for invoice or statement layouts, by allowing the user to draw the box for customer address, invoice number, lines, totals etc. The program will then figure out how to translate the dimensions and positions of the various boxes into print locations to store in the layout definition file, which is later used by an accounts system to print the various reports. Note that for various reasons (chiefly that the accounts system is non-Windows), placing text into Word or similar products and having them print the document is not an option. I can edit the document layout file by hand of course, but it's not very user-friendly.

As you might imagine, searches for "form editor", "layout editor" and the like bring many hundreds of irrelevant results. The frustrating thing is that I have seen a very relevant article, but lost the bookmark.

I am hoping someone has some pointers.

---

Thanks, this sounds more complicated than I imagined. I *really* wish I could find the original article I lost, as it was pretty clear on how to go about this in vb.net.

Because it's a layout for a printed form, I think that cuts down the complexity quite a lot - I only really need to store size and position of each print area, along with font, alignment and colour information, and possibly a filename for a graphic if a logo is required. The layout definition file format is entirely under my control.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should have great knowledge of the language/APIs you're using, and in fact you *really* should specify if you're using Windows.Forms, WPF, GTK#, etc. Make sure you're **very** good on that.

Then, you should think of a format for your form editor to store the forms. Usually, form editors use XML. If you also want to follow that trend, you **REALLY** should learn a good XML API for VB.

Finally, plan your steps carefully:

1. Do you want to use the custom text field controls provided by your API, or do you want to draw them manually(if so, then you'll need to learn a drawing API)?
2. Make sure you understand the layout definition file format very well.

Now, it's the time to start a proof-of-concept: create a simple editor that can load/save forms and add buttons to them. This will probably be hardest step to figure out. You may need to deal with events and several other stuff, but eventually it'll work(if not, then you may ask again).
Finally, just add the features you need, such as layout definition file output, new controls, control moving/resizing, etc.

If you need anything else(including more specific instructions), just ask.

Answer (score 0):

i remember developing exactly this kind of printout form editor in vb6, some 10 years ago iirc. not sure i can still find the sources sadly: indeed i found this question because i need to write another and was hoping to find some code to start from instead of doing it from scratch once again. 
anyway, the way i done implemented it, more or less, was like this:

- one custom control for the page background, displaying a light grid, and reacting to mouse events (eg, show a menu on right click);
- each field was a windowless custom control, displaying a light grid too, one cell for each (fixed width) char. it also reacted to mouse events so that it could be moved around and resized; when i say windowless i mean "not having an hwnd", a kind of optimization that allowed placing lots of control instances without worrying about the impact on resources; if you are going to use .net you couldn't care less but if you use vb6 it does make a difference;
- one property grid like the one of vb6 showing properties of the selected field(s). in my case, i could set the style of the text (compressed, expanded, bold) and an expression used at runtime to retrieve the value to be printed;
- loading a layout file would size the page and instantiate a field control for every field in the file;
- saving wrote out the page properties (size, name, etc) then enumerate the collection of fields and wrote out their properties;
- i didn't use xml because the file format was already fixed, as it was used by the engine that did the actual printing; xml would only have made my life easier, no need to write a custom parser for the data file format.
- the requirement was handling dot matrix printers only but luckily i didn't cut any corners and i could easily adapt it to also handle more precise placement and sizes of the fields. what i mean simply is, i resisted the temptation to use row and column coordinates and used twips instead; it took a little more thinking about the math but no rocket science definitely.

all in all it wasn't that hard to do and it came out very nice, it resembled a bit the form editor of "crystal reports".
i remember spending some time to get the details right, e.g. grid snapping at different character widths, resizing the fields when changing text styles like condensed or expanded without them jumping around because of rounding errors, things like that. don't let this scare you, keep in mind you don't have to take care of everything from the start, just be a little careful not to block the possibility of doing it a later time.

nowadays i wouldn't advice vb6 much, unless that's what you know best and need to produce a .exe not depending on the .net framework being installed on the target machines.
if instead you choose to go with .net i think it would be a good chance to learn wpf if you don't know it already, it makes for some impressive graphics even more than windows.forms.